# hibernate3-maven-plugin hbm2ddl goal ignores sequence definitions and generates default hibernate_sequence instead

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, ddl, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I have JPA annotated entity with ID defined as auto-generated property using sequences. But when I am trying to generate DDL with hibernate3-maven-plugin then my defined sequences are not generated, instead hibernate_sequence is there.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DUMMY")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "DUMMY_SEQ")
public class Dummy {
    private Long pk;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PK", nullable = false )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DUMMY_SEQ")
    public Long getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(Long pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }
}
```

I am expecting something like:

```
create sequence DUMMY_SEQ;
```

in generated DDL. What I am doing wrong?
hibernate3-maven-plugin version is 2.2
hibernate-entitymanager version 3.4.0.GA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined name of database sequence. Attribute *name* in SequenceGenerator is only name of the SequenceGenerator itself, not the name of the sequence in database. Result is that provider default, in this case *hibernate_sequence* is used. To affect name of the sequence, use [sequenceName](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#sequenceName%28%29) attribute:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "DUMMY_SEQ", sequenceName="DUMMY_SEQ")
```